# Flutter with an SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, flutter

I want to create a Flutter Android app for an existing project created using the WAMP stack (Apache, MySQL, PHP) and we used PHPmyAdmin to manage the SQL database. It is currently a web-app that lets registered vendors sell tokens/coupons that can be used by customers to make purchases in their stores.

That being said, I am open to suggestions involving any kind of database, language, framework and/or service, as long it fulfills our need, i.e, security and linking Flutter to an existing SQL database.

P.S. I know how to wire-up Firebase with a Flutter project but don't exactly know if I can link the Cloud Firestore with the SQL database. Suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

While you can access the sql database directly via [sqljocky5](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqljocky5) you shouldn't give the app access to your database directly.

You should rather create a web endpoint which manages all that. E.g. when the user buys something your app sends a [http request](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dio) to your server which then checks whether the purchase is verified (you can do that over google & apples servers if you use In-App purchases, which I strongly recommend as Apple prohibits third party transactions) then manages the SQL entry and gives back whatever you need (in your case a coupon).

Answer (score 0):

"P.S. I know how to wire-up Firebase with a Flutter project but don't exactly know if I can link the Cloud Firestore with the SQL database. Suggestions are welcome" regarding above mentioned part of your question, as per my knowledge and exploration, it is possible to have SQL as well as No-SQL database into one project by following microservices architecture. You can create Flutter client application, which communicates with the microservices via their APIs. You can use HTTP requests or other communication protocols to interact with the microservices.

Comment: Looks like this isn't an answer but a comment... please provide specific details and codes as needed to get it qualified as an answer...